# Real time function ploting using ruby

Tags: ruby, function, plot, real-time

For my university assignment I need to plot (preferably in a real time second thread) a function where on every iteration I would get an 3 x-y pairs. What is the best library to do so?

I tried [rchart](http://amardaxini.github.io/rchart/line_plot_chart.html) gem but it's not a real time solution and also a need of creation Rdata object to add a points to is quite annoying.

Comment: chekout this [blog](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2012/05/31/the-nuts-and-bolts-of-our-ruby-based-realtime-charts-solution) may help you.

Comment: @GaganGami as I understood, it's some kind of server sided resource monitor while I need a simple math plot. Yet thanks for an answer!